# R Markdown Error in inherits(x, "list) object not found

Tags: r, r-markdown

Good Morning! 
In an R Markdown chunk, I am trying to use kable to spit out a table in rmarkdown. Here's my dummy data:

```
whytheerror <- data.frame(name=c('school1','school2','school3','school4','school5','school6','school7','school8','school9','school10','school11'), count=c(13,25,36,44,58,63,76,85,93,78,101), percent=c(.7,.6,.2,.32,.41,.44,.97,.02,.31,.5,.11), other_count=c(15,111,33,74,19,5,3,111,1,37,501), other_percent=c(.4,.6,.3,.39,.45,.5,.02,.4,.06,.64,.11))
```

Here's my code:

````
```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
kable(whytheerror [1:12, ], caption = "Respondent Breakdown")
```
````

and the error reads:

```
Error in inherits(x,"list"): object 'whytheerror ' not found calls: <Anonymous>...withCallingHandlers -> withVisible  -> eval  -> eval  -> kable  -> inherits
```

I'm having difficulty figuring out what this error means much less fixing it. can someone assist with either or both?

thank you

Comment: `name` has 12 elements, the others have 11. (`school3` appears twice.)

Comment: Thank you. This was a dummy data set for the sake of this question. I've edited the code though.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, as shown below. Can you run my code okay?

Comment: No I couldn't. I got the same error even with my dummy dataset :-(

Comment: So, you started a fresh R session, opened a new `Rmd` file, pasted it in, and then it gave you that same error when you ran it?

Comment: restarted the computer and r. in my rmarkdown file this code does not work but in a new one it does. i wonder if it's a conflict with knitr maybe? I can't seem to find the source of the issue.

Comment: Perhaps move your document piece by piece to a new file until it breaks? On the information given, I can't reproduce the error so can't offer any other suggestions.

Comment: thank you for your help...i did try a new file and got the error. this table in my project was created with dcast so it's actually two crosstab tables combined into one. i wonder if that's the cause of the error :-/

Answer (score 0):

This

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
whytheerror <- data.frame(name=c('school1','school2','school3','school4','school5','school6','school7','school8','school9','school10','school11'), count=c(13,25,36,44,58,63,76,85,93,78,101), percent=c(.7,.6,.2,.32,.41,.44,.97,.02,.31,.5,.11), other_count=c(15,111,33,74,19,5,3,111,1,37,501), other_percent=c(.4,.6,.3,.39,.45,.5,.02,.4,.06,.64,.11))
```

```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
library(knitr)
kable(whytheerror[1:11, ], caption = "Respondent Breakdown")
```
````

produces

[image]

No error.